# adding text to a file put contents (PHP)

Tags: php, xpath, echo

I'm very new to php. I understand that echo is how you output text, but not sure how to apply it with the below scenario. Below, data is being scraped and outputted. Wondering if there's a way with the file_put_contents to add a text to the output, and the text I'm trying to add is a "%". Reason is the output of the below code is a random number that changes daily, and it's in fact a percent, so I'd like to add that to the end of the output every time. 
Thanks so much for any assistance.

```
    // get japanchange
    function getJapanchange(){
    $doc = new DOMDocument;

    // We don't want to bother with white spaces
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

    // Most HTML Developers are chimps and produce invalid markup...
    $doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
    $doc->recover = true;

    $doc->loadHTMLFile('http://________________//global-
indices/');
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    $query = "//div[@class='MT10']";
    $entries = $xpath->query($query);
    foreach ($entries as $entry) {
        $result = trim($entry->textContent); 
        $ret_ = explode(' ', $result);
        //make sure every element in the array don't start or end with blank
        foreach ($ret_ as $key=>$val){
            $ret_[$key]=trim($val);
        }
        //delete the empty element and the element is blank "\n" "\r" "\t"
        //I modify this line
        $ret_ = array_values(array_filter($ret_,deleteBlankInArray));
        //echo the last element
        file_put_contents(globalVars::$_cache_dir . "japanchange", 
$ret_[56]);
    }
 }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the questions completely, so I'll address just one part: to append to a file, you use `file_put_contents($filename, $content, FILE_APPEND);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to add a % to the end of the output to the file your already using.  You could simple do

```
 file_put_contents(globalVars::$_cache_dir . "japanchange", 
$ret_[56].'%');
```

Comment: that did the trick! Thanks nigel, thought I needed to put an echo in there.